# Kafka in kubernetes throwing error - Broker may not be available in kubernetes

Tags: java, kubernetes, apache-kafka

I'm trying to create a kafka cluster in my kubernetes running in my raspberry pi.
I can confirm that my set up is good. Because when I tried to send a message on the topic the other brokers were able to recieve it.

NOTE : I tried that my doing *exec* into the pod then execute kafka commands to publish and consume topics

**kafka-0**
[send message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgTwB.png)

**kafka-1**
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hgTwB.png)

However, when i tried connecting my java application(quarkus) to that kafka cluster.
it is giving me errors.

```
2020-09-22 22:35:14,178 WARN  [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (vert.x-kafka-consumer-thread-0) [Consumer clientId=consumer-beee3a1f-1488-4761-95fe-45927e060e58-1, groupId=beee3a1f-1488-4761-95fe-45927e060e58] Connection to node 1 (/10.1.7.145:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2020-09-22 22:35:35,183 WARN  [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (vert.x-kafka-consumer-thread-0) [Consumer clientId=consumer-beee3a1f-1488-4761-95fe-45927e060e58-1, groupId=beee3a1f-1488-4761-95fe-45927e060e58] Connection to node 0 (/10.1.7.144:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
2020-09-22 22:35:56,187 WARN  [org.apa.kaf.cli.NetworkClient] (vert.x-kafka-consumer-thread-0) [Consumer clientId=consumer-beee3a1f-1488-4761-95fe-45927e060e58-1, groupId=beee3a1f-1488-4761-95fe-45927e060e58] Connection to node 2 (/10.1.7.146:9092) could not be established. Broker may not be available.
```

Here is my ***kubernetes yml***

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: kafka
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
  serviceName: kafka-hs
  replicas: 3
  updateStrategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
  podManagementPolicy: OrderedReady
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: kafka
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: kafka
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        image: mjayson/rpi-kafka
        resources:
         requests:
           memory: "1Gi"
           cpu: "500m"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 9092
          name: server
---
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: kafka-service
spec:
  type: LoadBalancer
  loadBalancerIP: 192.168.1.110
  selector:
    app: kafka
  ports:
  - name: kafka-http
    port: 9092
    targetPort: 9092
    nodePort: 32420
---
apiVersion: policy/v1beta1
kind: PodDisruptionBudget
metadata:
  name: kafka-pdb
spec:
  minAvailable: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: kafka
```

not sure what is causing this.

```
listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.1.7.144:9092
broker.id=0
advertised.listeners=PLAINTEXT://10.1.7.144:9092
num.network.threads=3
num.io.threads=8
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=102400
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs
num.partitions=1
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1
offsets.topic.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.replication.factor=1
transaction.state.log.min.isr=1
log.segment.bytes=1073741824
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000
auto.create.topics.enable=true
zookeeper.connect=,zk-0.zk-hs.default.svc.cluster.local:2181
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=6000
group.initial.rebalance.delay.ms=0
```

to sum up.. my java app is in my local maching that is trying to connect to kafka deployed in kubernetes that is in another machine.

I hope someone could help me out on this.

Thank

**IN ADDITION**
the full log is

```
2020-09-22 23:17:09,709 INFO  [io.sma.rea.mes.provider] (Quarkus Main Thread) SRMSG00217: Connecting com.PriceConverter#process to `[replicated-topic]` (org.eclipse.microprofile.reactive.streams.operators.core.PublisherBuilderImpl@4e5812df)
2020-09-22 23:17:09,753 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.cli.con.KafkaConsumer] (vert.x-kafka-consumer-thread-0) [Consumer clientId=consumer-9d59ead0-024a-4b33-982e-6a43915298be-1, groupId=9d59ead0-024a-4b33-982e-6a43915298be] Subscribed to topic(s): replicated-topic
2020-09-22 23:17:09,882 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.cli.Metadata] (vert.x-kafka-consumer-thread-0) [Consumer clientId=consumer-9d59ead0-024a-4b33-982e-6a43915298be-1, groupId=9d59ead0-024a-4b33-982e-6a43915298be] Cluster ID: 42EgVPROQFuyd-kGj_K7_g
2020-09-22 23:17:09,884 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.cli.con.int.AbstractCoordinator] (vert.x-kafka-consumer-thread-0) [Consumer clientId=consumer-9d59ead0-024a-4b33-982e-6a43915298be-1, groupId=9d59ead0-024a-4b33-982e-6a43915298be] Discovered group coordinator 10.1.7.144:9092 (id: 2147483647 rack: null)
2020-09-22 23:17:09,886 INFO  [org.apa.kaf.cli.con.int.AbstractCoordinator] (vert.x-kafka-consumer-thread-0) [Consumer clientId=consumer-9d59ead0-024a-4b33-982e-6a43915298be-1, groupId=9d59ead0-024a-4b33-982e-6a43915298be] (Re-)joining group
```

Comment: Are you trying to connect to this kafka statefulset from outside of the cluster?

Comment: yes sir.. that's why i created a load balancer service for me to connect outside

Comment: I believe your advertised listeners are incorrect (also Kafka is not an HTTP service, so that NodePort/LoadBalancer definition looks incorrect - esp since Kafka client must connect to individual brokers, not Load balancers). I suggest starting here - https://strimzi.io/

Comment: @OneCricketeer - you mean if i scale my brokers each of them have a separate service? also what would be the usual value of advertised listeners?

Comment: They would be separate pods of a deployment/service, yes. And each would need their individual advertised listeners to be some routable address to external servers. If you use Strimzi, Banzai, or Confluent Kafka Helm Charts/Operators, then they all assign these for you in some way.

Comment: I would love that to use.. however, there is no arm64 version for those. I opted to create one for my self.